# How to use loop in this case inside the function?

Tags: python

```py
def get_day_type(info):                                                   
    
    day_type = (info[info.find("(")+1:info.find(")")])

    holiday = ["Sun", "Sat"]                              
    if day_type not in holiday:
        day_type = ("weekday")
        return day_type
        
    else:
        day_type = ("weekend")
        return day_type
```

The problem that it´s printing the type of the first day only and ignore the rest.
for example:

```py
print(get_day_type("Normal: 2May2022(mon), 3May2022(tues), 18Mar2021(Sun)"))
```

it only prints:

```
weekday
```

But I want my output to print all types of days. for example :

```
weekday

weekday

weekend
```

Note: I need to follow the same format of info input:

Which is ==>clientType: 12May1995(mon), 10May1995(tues), ........etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
def get_day_type(info):                                                   
    values = info.split(",")
    output = []
    for value in values:
        day_type = (value[value.find("(")+1:value.find(")")])
    
        holiday = ["Sun", "Sat"]                              
        if day_type not in holiday:
            day_type = ("weekday")
            output.append(day_type)
            
        else:
            day_type = ("weekend")
            output.append(day_type)

    return output

print(get_day_type("Normal: 2May2022(mon), 3May2022(tues), 18Mar2021(Sun)"))
```

output is

```
weekday
weekday
weekend
```

It just splits the info on the commas. It then iterates through the list created and uses the code you had to get the weekday or weekend for each item in the list. The outputs are stored in a list and then returned.

Comment: Thank you ... it is solved now
is there a way to make the output be in list ??

Comment: If you change the return to `return output`, is that what you mean?

Comment: Woow ... i hope to be one day like you.. thank you so much

Comment: No problem. I edited the answer to reflect this change.